# Need assistance regarding downloading data using NSURLConnection

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlconnectiondelegate

My app is a messaging app, it can also send image files. I am just uploading as image on web server and on other side just sending its url, with NSURLConnection i am trying to download an image with UIProgressView as a download indicator, here is my code:

**This method is called when download button in uitableview is clicked, it removes the download button, add uiprogressview and start downloading**

```
-(void)downloadImage:(UIButton *)link
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[link superview];

    NSIndexPath *pathToCell = [tView indexPathForCell:cell];

    NSMutableDictionary *checkItHasFile = [messages objectAtIndex:pathToCell.row];

    NSString *str = [checkItHasFile objectForKey:@"hasFile"];

    if([str isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
        progress = [[UIProgressView alloc]initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleBar];
        progress.frame = CGRectMake(10, 50, 160, 30);
        progress.progress = 0.0;

        //progress.center = CGPointMake(23,21);

        [cell addSubview:progress];
    }

    UIButton *view = [[UIButton alloc]init];
    NSArray *subviews = [cell subviews];

    for (view in subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    //

    NSString *linkToPass = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"THE URL"];

    NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:linkToPass]
                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                          timeoutInterval:60.0];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if (theConnection)
    {
        nsmd = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Connection to server failed!");
    }
...
```

**This method is a NSURLConnection delegate to indicate about response, in this I am calculating response size**

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
        [self.resourceData setLength:0];
        self.filesize = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[response expectedContentLength]];
}
```

**This method is a NSURLConnection delegate to indicate about received data, I am updating progress bar by doing some calculation**

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    resourceData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    [self.resourceData appendData:data]; 
    NSNumber *resourceLength = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:[self.resourceData length]];

    [self.progress setProgress:[resourceLength floatValue] / [self.filesize floatValue] animated:YES];
}
```

I want to know when downloding is finished so i can also remove progress view for that the delegate method is connectionDidFinishLoading:connection of NSURLConnection.

Problem is it immediately triggers, so when progress view is animating the download progress this method also executes, if I am removing the progress view here, the progress view will disappear immediately with out indicating a complete download progress.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: for example,if an image is just 5kb your data connection will download it suddenly. Try to download a big image and is it act like the same now. Then I think you need to setProgress: method in didReceiveResponse: itself.So that you can show progress bar for little more.

Comment: let me try this.. thanks for reply :)

Comment: seems like my existing code with large file is not working properly, I am nsloging the downloading data, progress bar is not incrementing properly or get halts in middle while all data is downloaded :( ... what to do?

Comment: before downloading the gui freezes also.. its all async then why gui freeze...

Answer (score 0):

Define a method that removes the progressbar, then in your `- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` implementation, if the resource length is less than a certain amount you decide, call the remove method with a delay:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(removeProgressBar) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
```

otherwise call the same method without any delay.